# spark array of wrappedArray

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe in spark that is very complex. I'm trying to use a UDF that takes 2 columns and then runs a function on each row of each column at the same time.

each column has the following identical schema:

```
root
 |-- A: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

In some cases, the array will be empty and in other cases, it will have elements, the count will vary.

when I do .dtypes on a column I get:

```
test: Array[(String, String)] = Array((A,ArrayType(DoubleType,true)))
```

When I do a take(1) on one of the columns I get a

```
Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([WrappedArray(1234, 4567, 789, 1346)])
```

When I simply run a select on a column I get:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: array<double>]
```

My goal is to run a function that takes each column's same element.

```
def inRange = udf((A: ???, B: ??? ) => {
   //iterate over the array and run coolFunction(A(0),B(0))
 })
```

I'm running the udf in this

```
df.withColumn("coolFunction", coolFunction(df("A"), df("B")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your `udf` function using `collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Double]` as

```
def inRange = udf((A: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Double], B: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Double]) => {
  //iterate over the array and run coolFunction(A(0),B(0))
})
```

**Or** *you can also use the parent class of `WrappedArray` which are `IndexedSeq` or `Seq`*

```
def inRange = udf((A: collection.mutable.IndexedSeq[Double], B: collection.mutable.IndexedSeq[Double]) => {
  //iterate over the array and run coolFunction(A(0),B(0))
})
```

**Or**

```
def inRange = udf((A: Seq[Double], B: Seq[Double]) => {
  //iterate over the array and run coolFunction(A(0),B(0))
})
```

Comment: I'm going to try each out, are there any pros or cons to each?

Comment: I get a error of java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Unit is not supported for each.  df.withColumn("coolFunction", coolFunction(df("A"), df("B")))

Comment: I think that error is saying my function is returning nothing.. let me test it a few times.

Comment: You have to return a value from the udf function for a new column or replace an existing column

Comment: Google: a consequence of an action or event, especially when complex or unwelcome

Comment: So only the first worked the other had errors off the bat.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```scala
def inRange = udf((A: Seq[Double], B: Seq[Double]) => {
    //iterate over the array and run coolFunction(A(0),B(0))
})
```

Reference https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types